# How to mock cashier defaultPaymentMethod() while unit testing in laravel?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery, laravel-cashier

i am not being able to mock cashier's defaultPaymentMethod method while testing. i have a controller named PaymentController and there is method called exec() as below:

```
public function exec()
{
   $user = Cashier::findBillable(\Auth::user()->stripe_id);
   $paymentMethodId = $user->defaultPaymentMethod()->id;

   return $paymentMethodId;
}
```

i am retrieving paymentMethodId calling function defaultPaymentMethod() from trait ManagesPaymentMethods.php which is used in User.php Model.

Now i want to retrieve paymentMethodId by mocking defaultPaymentMethod() while writing test.

I mocked defaultPaymentMethod() method from model User::class as ManagesPaymentMethods.php trait is used in User.php model.

```
protected function setUp(): void
{
  parent::setUp();
  $this->setUpFaker();

  $this->user = User::factory()->create([
     'stripe_id' => Str::random(14)
  ]);
}

public function test_paymentmethod_id_is_retrieved()
{
  $defaultPaymentMethod = new BankAccount();

  $mock = Mockery::mock(User::class)->makePartial();
  $mock->shouldReceive('defaultPaymentMethod')
      ->once()
      ->andReturn($defaultPaymentMethod);

  $response = $this->actingAs($user)
            ->post($this->url);

  $this->asertEquals($response['paymentMethodId']->id, $defaultPaymentMethod->id);
}
```

Comment: so, what is the error you are getting? Is the mock just not working at all?

Comment: PHPUnit\Framework\ExceptionWrapper 

  No such customer: 'P19DuJwaBF4HY7'

  at vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php:38

Comment: That means `Cashier::findBillable(\Auth::user()->stripe_id)` is not able to find the user

Comment: i've dd($user) it can find the user related to stripe_id.

Comment: I have never used Stripe, but looks like `findBillable` is failing, not `stripe_id`. Check the `api key` you are using on your test, remember the user must exists on Stripe (use testing/sandbox api keys)